# The effect of potential energy in the absence of conservative force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, projectile

Imagine a hypothetical situation, where we throw a ball from the earth's surface and after certain time $t$ the ball's final velocity is equals to 0. And a that instance, gravity doesn't exist (someone turn gravity off). So what will happen to the stored potential energy of that ball? Will potential energy convert to kinetic energy in that hypothetical situation? If no then how would law of conservation of energy would hold?

Comment: You are essentially asking “If (some of) the laws of physics don’t hold, how do the (other) laws of physics hold?” To me, that doesn’t make sense.  They come as a package deal.

Comment: The law of energy conservation wouldn't hold true. And that is how you know that your scenario is impossible and unrealistic.

Comment: I do agree my scenario is unrealistic. So for this sake, see @anna v 's answer. He/she has provided a non hypothetical situation which questions the same thing.

Comment: and see my comment also in Anna V's answer. That's my whole argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes! Energy can never be created or destroyed! And certainly, the earth’s gravitational field cannot simply disappear!

But hypothetically:

If gravity could suddenly disappear, then presumably so would the object’s potential energy.

The fact that the object has potential energy to begin with, is because work is done on the object by earth’s gravitational field. The object's kinetic energy is being transferred to potential energy so that at the point it stops moving, its potential energy will be given by

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh $$

where $v$ is its launch velocity and $h$ its maximum height. As we can see, if suddenly $g=0$, it has no potential energy, but this would lead to a contradiction, because again  energy can never be (created or) destroyed.

Conservation of energy will not apply here in this hypothetical situation and this scenario is physically unrealistic, but interesting nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

> the ball's final velocity is equals to 0. And a that instance, gravity doesn't exist(someone turn gravity off).

Energy conservation holds in inertial frames.

> [In classical physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) and special relativity, an inertial frame of reference is a frame of reference that is not undergoing acceleration.

The frame "resting ball and somebody turns gravity off", is not an inertial frame, as there must be a lot of dp/dt in the physical process to turn gravity off.

Think of a doable experiment. Throw a proton off, perpendicular from a negatively charged plate until it stops. At the stopping place it has  potential energy. Turn the negative field off, maybe sliding a metal shield over it.This process changes inertial frames, sliding introduces dp/dt, so conservation of energy does not have to hold.

Comment: But I have learnt that law of conservation of energy would hold true even if there is external force but the external force must be conservative in nature . Hence, sliding an aluminium will might change tbe magnitude of F but F is electromagnetic force(conservative in nature) so why conservation of energy won't hold true? And thanks alot for providing a non hypothetical situation. I can now argue in a better way..

Comment: for conservativ forces the energy should be balanced there, in the total frame